# HTML Canvas not working for whatever reason

Tags: javascript, html

So I am very new to programming at all and it might seem obvious to you, but I can't figure out why the following code won't work (the first three lines of the script are nescessary for another part of the full Webpage, but I don't see why that would hinder the rest of the code working) :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

  <script>

    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Text und Hintergrund per Java erstellt, font-size ist hier fontSize";
    document.getElementById("demo2").style.background = "red";
    document.getElementsById("demo2").style.fontSize = "190%";


    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    // Create gradient
    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,200,0);
    grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
    grd.addColorStop(1,"white");
    // Fill with gradient
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.fillRect(10,10,150,80);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Html element"demo2" does not exists hence you are getting that error.  Please check for demo2 element in you html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine.

I removed the first 3 lines of code because the element dont exist and that crashes your JS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

  <script>

  

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    // Create gradient
    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,200,0);
    grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
    grd.addColorStop(1,"white");
    // Fill with gradient
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.fillRect(10,10,150,80);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, I was using the same JS-script for five different webpages. Now that you pointed it out I went back to my previous four test-pages and all of them were broken. 

Thank you very much.

Comment: or you just add an element `<div id="demo2"></div>` and it should work too

Answer (score 1):

As you said earlier the first three lines of your code is hinder working the rest of your codes.

### So why it is happening?

**The javascript is a single-threaded language** so it will go into your code line by line

```js
1| document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Text und Hintergrund per Java erstellt, font-size ist hier fontSize";
2| document.getElementById("demo2").style.background = "red";
3| document.getElementsById("demo2").style.fontSize = "190%";
...
```

So whenever you got this it will run the first line then the second, then the rest line by line. Due to this feature **whenever one of your lines throw and error the rest functionality will be stopped**.

### What we can do in your case then?

Since you got the same script for multiple pages, then **you should consider which part of code you want to run** (actually which part is runnable).

There are several ways to do this:

1. **Make conditions on your scripts**

In this approach you should define a set of condition to check whether the elements exist in the page or not, so your code should be something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

  <script>
    var demo2 = document.getElementById("demo2");

    if (demo2) {
      demo2.innerHTML = "Text und Hintergrund per Java erstellt, font-size ist hier fontSize";
      demo2.style.background = "red";
      demo2.style.fontSize = "190%";
    }

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    
    if (c) {
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      // Create gradient
      var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 200, 0);
      grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
      grd.addColorStop(1, "white");
      // Fill with gradient
      ctx.fillStyle = grd;
      ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 80);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

2. **Make your code modular**

In order to run each specific part of code you can create two different modules, so let's assume the first one is:

```js
// demo2.js
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Text und Hintergrund per Java erstellt, font-size ist hier fontSize";
document.getElementById("demo2").style.background = "red";
document.getElementsById("demo2").style.fontSize = "190%";
```

and the second part is:

```js
// canvas.js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
// Create gradient
var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 200, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
grd.addColorStop(1, "white");
// Fill with gradient
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 80);
```

and this is the page that you using demo2:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id='demo2'>
    ...
  </div>

  <script src="./demo2.js"></script> // I just assuemed they both are in same directory
</body>

</html>
```

and this is the page that you using canvas:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

  <script src="./canvas.js"></script> // I just assuemed they both are in same directory
</body>

</html>
```

3. **Create empty div's with `display: none;` in each page in order to prevent error (not preferable at all)**

This approach is not preferred at all because you will add a useless element to your DOM and only make your DOM bigger for no reason.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div style="display: none;" id="demo2"></div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

  <script>
    var demo2 = document.getElementById("demo2");
    demo2.innerHTML = "Text und Hintergrund per Java erstellt, font-size ist hier fontSize";
    demo2.style.background = "red";
    demo2.style.fontSize = "190%";

    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    // Create gradient
    var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 200, 0);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "white");
    // Fill with gradient
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 150, 80);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like this:

```js
const setup = () => {

  const demo2 = document.getElementById("demo2");
  if(demo2 !== null) {
    demo2.textContent = "Text und Hintergrund per Java erstellt, font-size ist hier fontSize";
    demo2.style.background = "red";
    demo2.style.fontSize = "190%";
  }

  const c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  if(c !== null) {
    let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    // Create gradient
    let grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,200,0);
    grd.addColorStop(0,"red");
    grd.addColorStop(1,"white");
    // Fill with gradient
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.fillRect(10,10,150,80);
  }

}

//load
window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```